# Logout in ExpressJS, PassportJS and MongoStore

Tags: mongodb, session, express, passport.js

Im using PassportJS for authentication and MongoDB for session

In app.js:

```
app.use(express.session({
    store: new MongoStore({
        db: mongoose.connection.db
    })
}));
```

For logout:

```
app.get('/logout', function(req, res){
    req.session.destroy(function (err) {
        res.redirect('/');
    });
});
```

In logout, do I need to remove session document in mongo?

Answer (score 2):

PassportJS added a [`logout()`](http://passportjs.org/guide/logout/) function to `req`.