# Store sessions in mongodb with connect-mongo and mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, locomotivejs

I am getting errors left and right while I try to configure the express.js session storage with mongodb.  I am using locomotive for my framework and have configured mongoose.

In my initializers directory for 02_mongoose.js I have this.

```
module.exports = function() {
    mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27018/basbac');
    mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);
}
```

I know I have a connection to the database because I can pull my users in my controller.

```
DeveloperController.show = function() {

var self = this;
var user = mongoose.model('User');

user.find().exec(function(error, users) {

    if(error) {
        console.log(error);
    } else {
        self.res.json({response: { id: self.param('id'), api: self.param('api'), users: users } });    
    }

});
```

}

```
http://localhost:3000/developer/test/?api=hhfkgjhukdsfkjhvsduhvudhcsiudvlskejfbk

{
  response: {
  id: "test",
  api: "hhfkgjhukdsfkjhvsduhvudhcsiudvlskejfbk",
  users: [
    {
      _id: "52706695a43c83a739358de5",
      firstname: "cad",
      lastname: "bane",
      address: "duro",
      email: "cad@bane.com"
    },
    {
      _id: "52706695a43c83a739358de6",
      firstname: "jar jar",
      lastname: "binks",
      address: "naboo",
      email: "jarjar@binks.com"
    }
   ]
   }
}
```

Inside my config/all.js I have this as my configuration for sessions

```
var MongoStore = require('connect-mongo')(express);
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

this.use(express.cookieParser());

this.use(express.session({ 
    secret: 'keyboard cat',
    store: new MongoStore({
        mongoose_connection: mongoose.connection
    }) 
}));
```

But this throws an error.

```
this.db = new mongo.Db(options.mongoose_connection.db.databaseName,
TypeError: Cannot read property 'databaseName' of undefined
```

I also tried to do it like the connect-mongo docs where saying but I get an error with that as well.  (https://github.com/kcbanner/connect-mongo) mongoose_connection in the form: someMongooseDb.connections[0] to use an existing mongoose connection. (optional)

```
this.use(express.session({ 
    secret: 'keyboard cat',
    store: new MongoStore({
        mongoose_connection: mongoose.connections[0]
    }) 
}));
```

But I get the same error as before.

```
this.db = new mongo.Db(options.mongoose_connection.db.databaseName,
TypeError: Cannot read property 'databaseName' of undefined
```

I also tried to do as many articles are saying to do.  Here is one for example of someones working configuration ([Logout in ExpressJS, PassportJS and MongoStore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19450082/logout-in-expressjs-passportjs-and-mongostore))

```
this.use(express.session({ 
    secret: 'keyboard cat',
    store: new MongoStore({
        db: mongoose.connection.db
    }) 
}));
```

But that also produces an error, and I know that the db key is actually undefined

```
throw new Error('Required MongoStore option `db` missing');
```

What am I doing wrong to pass this connection into the new MongoStore?  When I start console.log() the mongoose object I am not able to find any information about the connection it is using.  I do see a base object but it does not have a db key inside it.  Do I need to pass some more options into the mongoose configuration?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the order in which Locomotive starts up. According to [the docs](http://locomotivejs.org/guide/initialization/):

> When a Locomotive application is started, it proceeds through a
>   sequence of steps:
>
> **Configure the Environment**
>
> In this step, config/environments/all.js is executed followed by the
>   configuration file for the current environment. For instance, when
>   running in development, config/environments/development.js is
>   executed.
>
> **Invoke Initializers**
>
> After the environment has been configured, initializers are invoked.
>   Initializers are used to configure sub-systems and connect to
>   databases, message queues, and other services utilized by the
>   application.

So when your environment code is being called, the initializer hasn't yet run and Mongoose isn't configured. Try moving the Mongoose setup to a separate file (I use `app/db/mongoose` myself, but that's a matter of personal preference) and `require` that in your environment file.

Comment: Thanks that works, I should have noticed that the order was out of place.  In all my searching I didn't even think of that.

Comment: @lumberjacked I actually had to check myself because to me it would make more sense to run the initializers before the environment files :)

Comment: I agree because it defeats the purpose of having development/production environments when configuration like this needs to run before hand.  I ended up duplicating my code because I wanted to use the environment files.  So now the connection and the session is repeated in both, I dont like that.

Comment: @lumberjacked depending on your need, you could use something similar to this: [gist](https://gist.github.com/robertklep/423696d4ca9635b9e36d). Or you could use `mongoose.createConnection` to create a specific new connection just for your session store.

Comment: Thats a good solution and it removes the duplication.  For my app I changed it slightly and used the switch statement from "Initializing Mongoose and MongoDB" (http://locomotivejs.org/guide/initialization/) but moved the mongoose.js file into the environments directory.